# Creating Category Url in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I create new category in Joomla 3.3 name `water`. I wan to display that category page like `http://www.myserver.com/Joomla/water` It's display 404 error.
If i create menu for that so it's display.
I Have many categories so help me to see category page without create menu.

Comment: You can't display a category without creating a menu item

Comment: But I have many categories so is there any extension for that?

Comment: Use [SH404 sef](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef/10134) component for this..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using url rewriting like below.

Put the following code in your joomla .htaccess file after **RewriteEngine On** statement.

```
 RewriteRule jcats/(.*)$ index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=mycontroller.viewitem&catalias=$1 [NC,L]
```

In this way any url like http://example.com/jcats/about-us would give you the last parameter as catalias variable and either with the help of a new component called com_mycomponent or com_content can be used to display the category or articles in the category.

I have done this beautifully for one of my website. If you need further help, **feel free to revert back**.